# passport.authentication needs a callback function

Tags: node.js, express

error is coming:

Error: Expected a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

error is in post signup function.
how to remove this error , as i wants to go at home page in post.authentication if success at signup page on failure.

[image]

Comment: postSignUp: passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
            successRedirect: '/home',
            failureRedirect: '/signup',
            failureFlash: true
        })

Comment: Share you current code as well

Comment: my current code is in the image that i shared along with question.

Comment: You are using postSignup. Change it to capital letter U (postSignUp)to match the function